# Mathematical Logic by Elliott Mendelson

Tags: logic

I’m reading *Introduction to Mathematical Logic by Elliott Mendelson*. He gave these three *axioms*:

[image]

And then he tried to prove that ¬ ¬ R  → R :

[image]

My question is: **what happened in line number 1 (when applying axiom (A3))?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity, rewrite axiom (A3) as follows:

> **(¬A → ¬D) → ((¬A → D) → A)**,

where (see page 3) **A** and **D** are *statement forms* (i.e. place-holders that stand for formulas whatever; see [Uses of *schema* in Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/schema/#UsesSche)).

Il Line 1, we perform the substitution of **B** in place of **A** and of **¬B** in place of **D**, getting:

> > **(¬B → ¬¬B) → ((¬B → ¬B) → B)**.

Comment: Thank you for your help

I'm new to this subject, so I'm still a little confused or maybe a lot.

You said “…we perform the substitution of B in place of A and of ¬B in place of D…” I understood the first substitution from B to A but I didn’t understand the second substitution, from ¬B to D? In other words, we have two signs (¬¬)?

Before I asked this question I did this: if ¬¬B is D and B is A, then the proof, in line 1, will go like this (as I understood with my little brain before I asked this question):

(¬B→¬¬¬B)→(( ¬B→¬¬B)→B)

What am I missing here?

Comment: @MohammadAltamimi - we have **exactly** to put **¬B** in place of **D** in every occurence where **D** is present. This means that the **D** occurrence will become **¬B** and the **¬D** occurrence will become **¬¬B**